# Overcomplete matrix eigendecomposition

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have something that looks similar to an eigenvalue decomposition, $$K = U^T \Sigma \, U$$ where $U \in \Bbb R^{d \times n}$ and the diagonal $\Sigma \in \Bbb R^{d \times d}$. Matrix $K$ is full rank and $U^TU = I_n$ is the identity in $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$. Oddly, $d$ is much larger than $n$, $d \gg n$. I would like to know the eigenvalue decomposition of $K$ efficiently. Are there any tricks to do it efficiently?

Comment: Does $\Sigma$ have positive diagonals?

Comment: Yes it does and K is positive semi definite

Answer (score 1):

If $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite, we may define the matrix $\Sigma$ as
$$
\Sigma = P^t \Gamma^2 P 
$$
where $P$ is a permutation matrix and the $m \times m$ diagonal matrix $\Gamma^2$ is positive definite.  Then the matrix $K$ can be written in the form
$$
K = W^t \Gamma^2 W = (\Gamma W)^t (\Gamma W)
$$
where $m \le d$,
$$
W = PU = P_{11} U_1 + P_{12}U2
$$
$$
P = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
       P_{11} & P_{12} \\
       P_{21} & P_{22} 
     \end{array} \right] , \;\;\; 
  U = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
       U_1 \\
        U_2
       \end{array} \right] .
$$
The matrix $W$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $P_{11}$ is an $m \times m$ matrix.

The eigenvalues of the matrix $K$ are given by the singular values squared of the matrix $\Gamma W$. The corresponding eigenvectors are given by the right singular vectors of $\Gamma W$.

The SVD of $\Gamma W$ is usually computed in two steps:

Step 1: Compute the QR-factorization of $\Gamma W$:
$$ QR = \Gamma W 
$$ 
where the $n \times n$ matrix $R$ is upper triangular. The matrix $Q$, which has orthonormal columns, is not explicitly computed. Only $R$ is required.

Step 2: Compute the  SVD of $R$, 
$$
R = \Phi S \Psi^t
$$
where $\Phi^t \Phi = \Psi^t \Psi = I$ and $S$ is the singular value matrix. This can be done without explicitly computing $\Phi$. The required eigenvectors are given by $\Psi$. The eigenvalues of $K$ are given by the squares of the singular values.

The nominally expensive part is computing the SVD of $R$ but $R$ is a small $n \times n$ matrix and hence inexpensive.

If it is known that $m$ is nearly equal to $d$, then  the reduction using the permutational matrix can be skipped. In that case, we proceed by computing the $QR$-factorisation of $\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}U$ instead of $\Gamma W$.

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstood the question. In the case I am interested in d is larger than n and hence I have an over complete decomposition. Naively I could orthognalise U but that would be as costly as performing regular svd.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding your question. I have revised the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Vini for the detailed answer. However, is there any computational advantage to doing this over directly computing the svd of K, as the QR factorisation I assume will cost O(n^3)

Comment: First, you should compute eigenvalue decomposition of $K$, not the SVD. Secondly, the complexity of the QR-factorisation is O($m n^2$) . If $m<d$ then there is an advantage in doing the permutational reduction. With BLAS-3 operations, QR goes faster than the complexity indicates. Thirdly, since we are not forming the matrix $K$ explicitly and working with a Cholesky type factorisation, there is an accuracy improvement. Due to this "square-root" algorithm and we do not have a numerically damaging $A^tA$ or $AA^t$ type step. Finally, this algorithm works when $U$ is not an orthogonal matrix.